# Having mysql_fetch_array() error while trying to retrieve data from database

Tags: php

I am doing a summary shopping cart, trying out the tutorial on my own.
But I met some error.

it was stated that " Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.php on line 18"

I want to display the items that I've bought , so I pass back the items from the cart database. (Using dreamweaver tools, I just drag and drop it).
However, the items don't show, but it gave me this error instead.

May I know what is wrong with my code, putting the SQL injection aside (as I'm not using it, still trying on the basic).

```
<?php require_once('Connections/MyDatabase.php'); ?>
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php 
$cartTotal = 0;
if(isset($_POST['CheckoutBTN']))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
    $time=date('D,F j, Y, H:i:s A');
    $uname = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
foreach ($_SESSION["supermarketcart"] as $each_item)
    {

     $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $productdes = $row['description'];
    $price = number_format($row['price'],2);
    $size = $row['packaging'];
    $itemqty = $each_item['quantity'];

  $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
  $cartTotal = number_format($pricetotal + $cartTotal,2);

    $checkout="INSERT INTO supermarketcart (itemid, productdes, package, itemprice, qty, username, ddate) VALUES 
                           ('$item_id', '$productdes', '$size', '$price','$itemqty','$uname','$time')";
    mysql_query($checkout)or die(mysql_error());

       }
    }
}

?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_cart = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_USERNAME'])) {
  $colname_cart = $_SESSION['MM_USERNAME'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_cart = sprintf("SELECT * FROM supermarketcart WHERE username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_cart, "text"));
$cart = mysql_query($query_cart, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($cart);
$totalRows_cart = mysql_num_rows($cart);

mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_user_info = "SELECT * FROM user_data";
$user_info = mysql_query($query_user_info, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_info);
$totalRows_user_info = mysql_num_rows($user_info);
?>
```

Comment: can u add mysql_error() for the select query, most likely query is failing somewhere in the loop

Comment: do you mean like this?
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error()

Comment: yes just like what u did for insert query

Comment: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given 
this is the error

Comment: You should avoid using **Mysql_*** any more as it has been depreciated. You should check out [MySQLi](http://uk3.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: ok here the the another debug, for each of the select query echo them $sql. You can run those queries directly in the DB to see if it has some row or the query is correct to return some data.

Comment: @Styphon I've already stated that I'm trying out the basic, thus i'm not using MySQLi or PDO

Comment: @user3156220 doesn't matter. MySQLi is just as easy to use as MySQL. The statements are almost identical. You should not be using something that is depreciated and will be removed from PHP soon.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty it was stated that there things in the database, resource id#2, etc..

The part that is having the problem is this
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
as stated line 18

Comment: @Styphon is it? i didn't know about it, as my teacher told us to use MySQL

Comment: inside the loop initialize $sql = ''; before using it to mysql_query and see if this helps.

Comment: which part? I kind of confuse what you trying to say

Answer (score 0):

Following your code snippet, `$each_item['item_id']` is not checked if it is set with something inside. The subsequent query will fail sometimes (SQL fail if the WHERE close is empty)

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1");
```

so `$sql` will be set to `false`, and you get your error afterward.

You probably disabled the warning message so you dont get any information from remote mysql or about the unset `$each_item['item_id']`

Change the error reporting level and debug afterward : to do that, add this after `session_start();`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```